# What conditions does Euler midpoint and the classical fourth-order Runge-Kutta method; is absolutely stable

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods, eulers-method

> Question: Given the differential equation and its initial condition as
> $$dy/dx =-20xy^2 \quad\text{and} \quad y(1)=1$$
> respectively,  determine, under what conditions each of:

> (i)    Euler’s method;

> (ii)   the classical fourth-order Runge-Kutta method;

> is stable over the interval $1 \leq x \leq 2$, given that for this problem the maximum value of $xy$ occurs when $x = 1$.

I do not understand what this question is asking for.
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is "absolutely stable" in this context? The linearization at the limit point $y=0$ is zero, so the condition is that the sequence $y_n$ remains bounded, measured by the first value $y_0=1$ (at $x_0=1$)? Is that then $|y_n|\le 1$ or $y_n\in[0,1]$?

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann can just treat it as stable.

Answer (score 1):

The first observation is that if $y$ at some time during the numerical method takes a negative value, the exact solution will diverge towards $−∞$, and the numerical solution will follow. So what is observed is at least a move further away from the $x$-axis inside the integration interval $[1,2].

For the Euler method this excludes step sizes $\Delta x>0.05$, as that reaches negative values in the first step. For the RK4 method one can compute that the first step reaches negative values in the first step for $Δx>0.096927124$, however the following steps still could reach below the axis in the further steps.

Numerical experimentation gives the following plots and critical step sizes.

[image]